# How can I get a notification for finished processes inside a graphical user interface?

Tags: notification, notify-osd, notification-area

**Example:**

[image]

**Seeking solution:**

I would like to receive a notification of any kind, once this process has finished without me having to periodically switch to the window and check if the process has finished.

Comment: No, unless you modify the source code of the GUI program that you're using. Of course, that program has to be open-source to begin with.

Comment: Assuming that when you say "this process has finished" that there is an actual process that will finish, then if you could identify it (say with `ps -ef | grep pattern`) you could write a script to loop while the process exists, and once it goes away pop up a window to inform you of the fact using xmessage.  No doubt there are smarter ways of detecting the process finishing and notifying the user...